# Pong game in python. Score and out-of-screen check

Tags: python, pygame

Last week we did a *pong game*.

Here's the code:

```py
import pygame

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

class Ball:
    # свойства
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 20, 20)
        self.rect.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2)
        self.dx = 5     # скорость по иксу
        self.dy = 5     # скорость по игреку
        self.game_over = False

    # методы
    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, self.rect.center, 10)     # 10 - радиус мяча

    def move(self):
        x, y = self.rect.center
        x += self.dx
        y += self.dy
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        if y > SCREEN_HEIGHT or y < 0:
            self.dy *= -1
        if x > SCREEN_WIDTH or x < 0:
            #self.dx *= -1
            print('Game Over')
            self.game_over = True          

class Paddle:   # ракетка
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 10, 100)

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, self.rect)

# ----------------  проверка на столкновение -------------------------- #

def check_collision(ball, paddle):
    if ball.rect.colliderect(paddle.rect):
        ball.dx *= -1

# -------------------- управление ракетками --------------------------- #

def control_human(paddle):
    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        paddle.rect.y -= 5
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        paddle.rect.y += 5

def control_computer(paddle, ball):
    # если мяч летит от компьютера, то ничего не делать
    if ball.dx < 0:
        return
    # если мяч выше ракетки, то двигаем ракетку вверх
    if ball.rect.y < paddle.rect.y:
        paddle.rect.y -= 5
        if paddle.rect.y < 0:
            paddle.rect.y = 0
    # если мяч ниже ракетки, то двигаем ракетку вниз
    if ball.rect.y > paddle.rect.y:
        paddle.rect.y += 5
        #if paddle.rect.y + 100 > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
        #    paddle.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 100
        if paddle.rect.bottom > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            paddle.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT    

# --------------------------------------------------------------------- #
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

# ----------------  создаем объекты для игры -------------------------- #

ball = Ball()
left_paddle = Paddle(30, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2 - 50)
right_paddle = Paddle(SCREEN_WIDTH - 40, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2 - 50)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Lucida Console", 30)
label = font.render("G A M E   O V E R", 1, (255, 0, 0, 255))

# --------------------  главный цикл игры ----------------------------- #
while True:
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    if not ball.game_over:
        ball.move()
        ball.draw(screen)
        control_human(left_paddle)
        control_computer(right_paddle, ball)
        left_paddle.draw(screen)
        right_paddle.draw(screen)
        check_collision(ball, left_paddle)
        check_collision(ball, right_paddle)
    else:
        screen.blit(label, (50, 100) )
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

We need to add **an out-of-screen check on the human player's racket**.
**Add counting of successful kicks to the ball for each player and display the current score on the screen**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "out-of-screen check" of the human paddle can be done in `control_human`. If the paddle is moved up, the final paddle top position is the maximum ([`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)) of 0 and `paddle.rect.top-5`. If the paddle is moved down, then the final paddle bottom position is the minimum ([`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)) of `SCREEN_HEIGHT` and `paddle.rect.bottom+5`:

```py
def control_human(paddle):
    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        paddle.rect.top = max(0, paddle.rect.top - 5)
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        paddle.rect.bottom = min(SCREEN_HEIGHT, paddle.rect.bottom + 5)
```

---

To count the score add a return value to the function `check_collision`. The function has to return `True` if the ball collides with the paddle. Else the function returns `False`:

```py
def check_collision(ball, paddle):
    if ball.rect.colliderect(paddle.rect):
        ball.dx *= -1
        return True
    return False
```

Add a `score` and increment the score if `left_paddle` collides with `ball`. Convert the score to a string by [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str), render the string and blit it to the display:

```py
score = 0
while True:
    # [...]

    if not ball.game_over:
        ball.move()
        ball.draw(screen)
        control_human(left_paddle)
        control_computer(right_paddle, ball)
        left_paddle.draw(screen)
        right_paddle.draw(screen)

        if check_collision(ball, left_paddle):
            score += 1

        check_collision(ball, right_paddle)

        score_label = font.render(str(score), 1, (255, 0, 0, 255))
        screen.blit(score_label, (10, 10))

    else:
        screen.blit(label, (50, 100) )

    # [...]
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

class Ball:
    # свойства
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 20, 20)
        self.rect.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2)
        self.dx = 5     # скорость по иксу
        self.dy = 5     # скорость по игреку
        self.game_over = False

    # методы
    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, self.rect.center, 10)     # 10 - радиус мяча

    def move(self):
        x, y = self.rect.center
        x += self.dx
        y += self.dy
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        if y > SCREEN_HEIGHT or y < 0:
            self.dy *= -1
        if x > SCREEN_WIDTH or x < 0:
            #self.dx *= -1
            print('Game Over')
            self.game_over = True          

class Paddle:   # ракетка
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 10, 100)

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, self.rect)

# ----------------  проверка на столкновение -------------------------- #

def check_collision(ball, paddle):
    if ball.rect.colliderect(paddle.rect):
        ball.dx *= -1
        return True
    return False

# -------------------- управление ракетками --------------------------- #

def control_human(paddle):
    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        paddle.rect.top = max(0, paddle.rect.top - 5)
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        paddle.rect.bottom = min(SCREEN_HEIGHT, paddle.rect.bottom + 5)

def control_computer(paddle, ball):
    # если мяч летит от компьютера, то ничего не делать
    if ball.dx < 0:
        return
    # если мяч выше ракетки, то двигаем ракетку вверх
    if ball.rect.y < paddle.rect.y:
        paddle.rect.y -= 5
        if paddle.rect.y < 0:
            paddle.rect.y = 0
    # если мяч ниже ракетки, то двигаем ракетку вниз
    if ball.rect.y > paddle.rect.y:
        paddle.rect.y += 5
        #if paddle.rect.y + 100 > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
        #    paddle.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 100
        if paddle.rect.bottom > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            paddle.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT    

# --------------------------------------------------------------------- #
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

# ----------------  создаем объекты для игры -------------------------- #

ball = Ball()
left_paddle = Paddle(30, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2 - 50)
right_paddle = Paddle(SCREEN_WIDTH - 40, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2 - 50)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Lucida Console", 30)
label = font.render("G A M E   O V E R", 1, (255, 0, 0, 255))

# --------------------  главный цикл игры ----------------------------- #
score = 0
while True:
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    if not ball.game_over:
        ball.move()
        ball.draw(screen)
        control_human(left_paddle)
        control_computer(right_paddle, ball)
        left_paddle.draw(screen)
        right_paddle.draw(screen)
        if check_collision(ball, left_paddle):
            score += 1
            print(score)
        check_collision(ball, right_paddle)
        score_label = font.render(str(score), 1, (255, 0, 0, 255))
        screen.blit(score_label, (10, 10))
    else:
        screen.blit(label, (50, 100) )

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is code with out-of-screen check for human paddle and counter for human paddle:

```
import pygame

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

class Ball:
    # свойства
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 20, 20)
        self.rect.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2)
        self.dx = 5     # скорость по иксу
        self.dy = 5     # скорость по игреку
        self.game_over = False

    # методы
    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, self.rect.center, 10)     # 10 - радиус мяча

    def move(self):
        x, y = self.rect.center
        x += self.dx
        y += self.dy
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        if y > SCREEN_HEIGHT or y < 0:
            self.dy *= -1
        if x > SCREEN_WIDTH or x < 0:
            #self.dx *= -1
            print('Game Over')
            self.game_over = True

class Paddle:   # ракетка
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 10, 100)

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, self.rect)

    def on_ball_collision(self, ball):
        pass

# ----------------  проверка на столкновение -------------------------- #

def check_collision(ball, paddle):
    if ball.rect.colliderect(paddle.rect):
        paddle.on_ball_collision(ball)
        ball.dx *= -1

# -------------------- управление ракетками --------------------------- #

def control_human(paddle):
    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        paddle.rect.y = max(0, paddle.rect.y - 5)
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        paddle.rect.y = min(SCREEN_HEIGHT - paddle.rect.height, paddle.rect.y + 5)

def control_computer(paddle, ball):
    # если мяч летит от компьютера, то ничего не делать
    if ball.dx < 0:
        return
    # если мяч выше ракетки, то двигаем ракетку вверх
    if ball.rect.y < paddle.rect.y:
        paddle.rect.y -= 5
        if paddle.rect.y < 0:
            paddle.rect.y = 0
    # если мяч ниже ракетки, то двигаем ракетку вниз
    if ball.rect.y > paddle.rect.y:
        paddle.rect.y += 5
        #if paddle.rect.y + 100 > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
        #    paddle.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 100
        if paddle.rect.bottom > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            paddle.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT

# --------------------------------------------------------------------- #
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

# ----------------  создаем объекты для игры -------------------------- #

class HumanPaddle(Paddle):
    def __init__(self, x, y, font):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.font = font
        self.count = 0
        self.label = self.font.render("Count: {}".format(self.count), 1, (255, 0, 255, 255))

    def on_ball_collision(self, ball):
        self.count += 1
        self.label = self.font.render("Count: {}".format(self.count), 1, (255, 0, 255, 255))

    def draw_count(self, x, y):
        screen.blit(self.label, (x, y) )


ball = Ball()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Lucida Console", 30)
left_paddle = HumanPaddle(30, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2 - 50, font)
right_paddle = Paddle(SCREEN_WIDTH - 40, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2 - 50)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
label = font.render("G A M E   O V E R", 1, (255, 0, 0, 255))

# --------------------  главный цикл игры ----------------------------- #
while True:
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    if not ball.game_over:
        ball.move()
        ball.draw(screen)
        control_human(left_paddle)
        control_computer(right_paddle, ball)
        left_paddle.draw(screen)
        right_paddle.draw(screen)
        check_collision(ball, left_paddle)
        check_collision(ball, right_paddle)
        left_paddle.draw_count(10, 10)
    else:
        screen.blit(label, (50, 100) )
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

---

The out-of-screen check is done by this code:

```
def control_human(paddle):
    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        paddle.rect.y = max(0, paddle.rect.y - 5)
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        paddle.rect.y = min(SCREEN_HEIGHT - paddle.rect.height, paddle.rect.y + 5)
```

The counter is done by enhancing the `Paddle` with `def on_ball_collision(self, ball)` event and then subclassing the `Paddle` on the left as `HumanPaddle` that has this event implemented.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!